# How to read target extent from a huge TIFF file by LibTiff.Net library

Tags: tiff, libtiff.net

I have a big tiff file which I don't want to load it into memory one time (That will cause my application takes so many memory), I want to load target part of it one time and show this part in screen.
I am trying to use LibTiff.net library for implement this, but I haven't found a suitable API for it.

Currently I can just load that by calloc a new array (very big!) then call ReadRGBAImageOriented function for load the RGBA value for it.

Do someone have experience on it?

Thanks

Comment: I think that [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9009999/249690) to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9004149/249690) should help you. Or at least should give you some information for a start.

Comment: Thanks for your quickly answer! I finally use ReadRGBAStrip solve that. In fact I am a totally beginner for Tiff format, I just understand what strip stand for and what tile stand for. But for scanline I still haven't have a good understanding.

Comment: Hi Bobrovsky, will your library support geoTiff read the near future?

Comment: the library should support such files just fine. Please don't use comments for *new question* next time. Doing so hides information from other site visitors.

Comment: OK, I will create new question next time. Currently this library can read geotiff just like tiff, and can read custom tag like 34735(GeoKeyDirectoryTag) succeed, but it's not easy to get boudingbox and projection information from file correct, will you provide some new functions for that so user can read these information easier or do you have some existing sample for this? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, we have no plans for that. LibTiff.Net is just a port of libtiff. It supposed to do all of what libtiff does (and in the same way) and nothing more.