# Reduce Image File Size 'System.OutOfMemoryException'

Tags: c#, .net, image, bitmap, system.drawing

I write a simple code to reduce image file size.
This code can work with small file size, but when run with bigger file size get an error. 
This is the error,

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
>   Additional information: Out of memory.
>   [image]

All the image file size bigger than 800MB. And image type is JPEG and TIFF to convert to JPEG.
This is my code

```
public void GetImageFile()
    {
        string path1 = string.Empty;
        string fileName = string.Empty;
        string fileFolder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["locationFrom"];
        string[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles(fileFolder, "*");

        foreach (string file in fileList)
        {
            fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);

            path1 = "\\Photo\\newPath\\" + fileName;

            Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(file);
            ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder =
                System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;

            EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

            EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 50L);
            myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
            bmp1.Save(path1, jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters);

        }
    }
```

The error happen on this line,

> Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(file);

Is there any suggestion I can use to reduce/compress the image file size without reduce the image quality?

Comment: Does it run out of memory on the *first* image, or when processing multiple images?

Comment: @dbc yes..same for the first image and multiple image..

Comment: Do you run out of memory loading a huge tiff file, or a huge jpeg?  If tiff, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004149/open-huge-tif-in-net-and-copy-parts-to-new-image.  Also, are you running a 32 bit process or a 64 bit process?

Comment: @dbc it was tiff file and it's 32bit..

Comment: 1) Can you switch to 64 bit?  2) Try [Open huge TIF in .NET and copy parts to new image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004149/open-huge-tif-in-net-and-copy-parts-to-new-image) and see if it helps. 3) Try [How do I create a (32-bit) .NET application to use 3 GB RAM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464458/how-do-i-create-a-32-bit-net-application-to-use-3-gb-ram).